# Casting to generic abstract class shows T as unresolved symbol

Tags: c#, generics

Let's say that I have this:

```
public abstract class myClass<T> : Ob<T> where T : Ob<T>, new()
```

Now in a method defined inside abstract myClass, I create an object of class myType and on a method defined inside myType, I pass the abstract class myClass calling it.

So in my myType class, I have:

```
public void myMethod(object caller)
```

My question is, how do I cast object caller to the type of the abstract class that called it?

I tried

```
(myClass<T>)
```

and

```
(myClass)
```

but both failed.

Generics make my head hurt.

Comment: On a side note, is there a reason you have a "recursive" Ob<T> where T:Ob<T>? I am interested to know some good reason behind it.

Comment: I inherited that code and was trying to figure that out myself :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with **as**, as follows:

```
public void MyMethod(object caller)
{
    myClass<T> test = caller as myClass<T>;
    if (test != null)
    {
         // Use test here
    }
}
```

That being said, if you are always passing in a known `myClass<T>` it'd probably be cleaner to just use:

```
public void MyMethod(myClass<T> caller)
{
     // Use caller directly...
}
```

---

Edit: To demonstrate, here's a small sample:

```
using System;

public class myClass<T> where T : new()
{
    public T Value;

    public void CopyFromSecond(object caller)
    {
        myClass<T> test = caller as myClass<T>;
        this.Value = test.Value;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        myClass<int> test = new myClass<int> { Value = 3 };
        myClass<int> test2 = new myClass<int> { Value = 5 };

        Console.WriteLine(test.Value);
        test.CopyFromSecond(test2);
        Console.WriteLine(test.Value);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

This prints 3 then 5, as expected.

---

Edit 2:

If you're trying to find the type of T from another `myClass<T>`, you'll need to use reflection.  The method you need is [Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx).

Comment: If use the 'as' , I still get an error stating the T from myClass<T> is undefined

Comment: His problem is that he's doing it from _another_ class, method of which is called by some `myClass<T>`. And he wants to find out that `T`.

Comment: @Pavel: I'm not 100% sure what he wants - but I added sample code, plus linked to the Type method required to get the typeof T.   If you're correct in his desires, reflection is the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even need the cast in the first place? Perhaps you want:

```
public void myMethod<T>(myClass<T> caller)
```

Otherwise, the answer to your question is - you cannot, because you do not know which particular specialization of `myClass` called you.

Comment: Good point, but in 

public void myMethod<T>(myClass<T> caller)


the T is still not valid.

Comment: Er, why? The declaration introduces a new generic type parameter. Are you sure you didn't miss `<T>` after `myMethod`? If you didn't, and it still doesn't compile, then what is the error message?