# How to cast by generic type

Tags: c#, generics, casting, abstract-class

I would like to use a generic type for casting, is there any simple way to do this? Here is an example:

```
var resource = viewBase.getAnyInstance(resourceName) as T;
```

Where T is one of existing type.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: That doesn't actually make sense.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you saying in a generic method you'd like to do this?  And it should be noted `T` must be constrained to `where T : class` since `as` returns `null` if it is not the requested type, and value types can't be `null`.

Comment: I would like to use parametrized T and cast by it(T may be one of my custom classes)

Comment: That should just work.  Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I did. But I am still learning C#, so I could do an elementary mistake. I will keep trying..

Comment: It would really help us here if you gave us the error/problem you are seeing when doing it.  Often an error message speaks louder than 1000 words.  Also see my note above on constraining `T` to `class` or it won't work.  you can't have an unconstrained `T` and use `as` because things like `var x = y as int;` makes no sense.

Comment: You can, of course, use a regular cast: `var resource = (T) viewBase.getAnyInstance(resourceName);`

Comment: I tried to do it this way: var T = typeof(Class1ResourcesBase); var resource = (T)viewBase.getAnyInstance(resourceName);

Comment: @AboutNothing: You can't do that in that way, you can't create a generic type parameter from a typeof statement.

Comment: Wait, is Class1ResourceBase a class?  an object?  What exactly is it?

Comment: So why not just cast it?  `var resource = (Class1ResourceBase) viewBase.getAnyInstance(resourceName)`;

Comment: Yes, just casting to particular class type finally worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A `Generic` is a fancy way of handling multiple types of `Objects` without any clear concise knowledge of what your manipulating.  That in itself creates quite a bit of flexibility, as it can alleviate several issues you may encounter when you utilize `Boxing` and `Unboxing`.

To help clarify `Generics` for you, I'll use the `List` example.  Mostly because at least for me it really solidified `Casting` with `Generics`.

**The problem, if you've tried to `Cast` between `List Generics` you'll quickly see... You can't.**

In my example I'll use Shapes, so in theory you have three classes.

Classes:

- Circle
- Square
- Polygon

When you learned `Casting` this is quite easy to do.

```
int i = 10;
string j = "I have ";
string d = j + (string)i;
```

And you've converted your `variable i` into a `String`.  As long as the type fits; your okay.  If it doesn't you'll encounter exceptions.

When you introduce `Generics` it changes quickly.

Now, as you saw above we have three `Classes` that represent `Shapes`.  Now a `Shape` will be a common `Object` which technically should be inherited by those `Shapes`.  So `List<Square>` can't inherit from `List<Circle>` and vice-versa.  It seems quantitative, seems plausible.  But it isn't, why?

It's due to the `Constructed Type` in which the conversion of data takes place.

So in some instances for these `List` you'd have to write a `Loop` to transfer data from one `List` to another.

So this is where `Generics` can be quite useful.

```
// Square List:
List<Square> lSq = new List<Square>();

   lSq.Add(new Square("Red Square"));
   lSq.Add(new Square("Blue Square"));
```

We've created a `Square List` to hold our object.

```
// Generic Shape
List<Shape> shp = lSq.ConvertAll(
   new Converter<Square, Shape>(lSqToshp));
```

We've actually used a `Generic` to `Cast` those values directly into our new `List`.

Now, I understand that isn't your question.  Your asking:

> I would like to use a generic type for casting, is there any simple way to do this?

The short answer, yes.  But the variation will vary on your goal and usage.  You've mentioned that it is an `Abstract Class`.

Now, are you trying to do something like:

```
public void SomeMethod(object caller)
{
   someClass<T> info = caller as someClass<T>;
   if (info != null)
   {}
}
```

That would describe `Casting` to an `Abstract Class`.

```
var detail = (SomeClassBase)viewBase.getAnyInstance(detailName);
```

There are a lot of variations.

A post that sounds similar to your vague question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175235/casting-to-generic-abstract-class-shows-t-as-unresolved-symbol). Another post that may provide more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949406/best-way-to-do-this-generic-abstract-class-in-c).  Something to note, if your trying to pass an `Object` that is already known, why not just use the caller directly?

Unfortunately, your question will require more details for a better answer.  But it sounds like your having difficulties understanding `Generics`.

Comment: Thank you so much for answer and comments. I am currently looking into it and trying to understand the problematic in more complex way. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. Hopefully my response helped a bit. It helped me understand but others it may not.